# How to use XAML icons with Ribbon?

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons

I have a Ribbon that is currently configured like this to show icons:

```
<Style x:Key="PrintMenuButton" TargetType="rib:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem">
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="/styles/metro/print.png"/>
</Style>
```

I want to switch to XAML (or SVG) vector icons. I got Syncfusion Metro Studio that spits out icons in the following format:

```
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
 <Grid>
  <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Width="256" Height="256" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  <Path Data="M19.833,0L32.5,0 32.5,19.833999 52.334,19.833999 52.334,32.500999 32.5,32.500999 32.5,52.333 19.833,52.333 19.833,32.500999 0,32.500999 0,19.833999 19.833,19.833999z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FF228B22" Width="138" Height="138" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
<Path.RenderTransform><TransformGroup>
<TransformGroup.Children>
<RotateTransform Angle="0" />
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
</TransformGroup.Children>
</TransformGroup>
</Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
</Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

However, with my very limited skills in XAML I have a hard time mixing this together to work.

I put this icon (everything with Viewbox) inside ResourceDictionary and added x:Key="MyLovelyIcon", but it won't work and I am not sure why.

I would be grateful if someone could advise me how to glue those things together. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some poking around I got what I wanted:

```
<Style x:Key="PrintMenuButton" TargetType="rib:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem">
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{StaticResource XamlIcon_Misc_Print}"/>
</Style>
```

and

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="XamlIcon_Misc_Print">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="M6.6669998,lots of digits"/>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

So basically I did away with Path and moved the data to Geometry object. If someone would like to comment on when to use one and when the other and how they differ, or spare a link to MSDN, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This is what I was looking for. Is there a way to  apply the the color of the  GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" from a style?

Comment: You can do:  GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource brBlack}" where brBlack is defined as <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brBlack">#FF000000</SolidColorBrush> Is that what you meant?

Comment: But if you meant like full-blown <Style> then I doubt, since this is defined on FrameworkElement and at least in this example we have GeometryDrawing which inherits from DispatcherObject and Freezable, but not FrameworkElement.